# TestCafe Requires Permission To Record Screen but permission is already granted on MAC

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have two TestCafe projects, when I tried to run the old one, it continuously requires Permission to record screen but permission is already granted.
The new testCafe project can run without this issue.

[Please click this link for the issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdPgn.png)

I use testCafe v1.18.1 in both projects.

My environment : MAC OS Montery v12.1

I've tried:

1. (-)delete button to delete testcafe record screen permission, and rerun testcafe and when the permission request prompt, I grant it.
2. reboot pc.
3. disable testcafe record screen permission and enable it.

but got no luck, does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you previously installed testcafe v1.17.2-rc, try removing the .testcafe-browser-tools folder from your home directory. If this does not help, I suggest you [create an issue i](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md)n the TestCafe GitHub repository with a sample project and a video to demonstrate how you reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue because I didn't notice that I installed a global version testcafe.